# How to delay some action in Android so that a task completes after a set Delay in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app in Android which has a few actions that need to be executed after a set period of time.

Anything which I can do to fulfil this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, then use the Android [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) to delay your task

In your activity's onCreate method do this:

```
 int any_delay_in_ms = 1000; //1Second interval
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        //TODO Perform your action here
    }, any_delay_in_ms);
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

```
    int delay = 1000;//1 sec, change it as per need
    //if you are not executing anything which need main thread 
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {

    }, delay);
    
    //if you are  executing anything which need main thread 
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {

    }, delay);
```